# IMHO, I am great?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I am not a native English speaker. I was wondering if the phrase "in my humble opinion, my  proposal is interesting because ..." is contradictory?

I am trying to say that something I proposed/said is interesting/valid (basically I am trying to defend some of my arguments against a certain criticism), but on the other hand I say "my humble opinion". Should I just remove this phrase in order to avoid contradiction? I was just trying to soften my words since I am writing to a higher authority.

Comment: Your title would be a bit much, but your quoted phrase is fine (perhaps it's a touch bombastic). The introductory clause is unnecessary, just tell us why your proposal is interesting!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "IMHO" a rude thing to say (or type)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/is-imho-a-rude-thing-to-say-or-type)

Comment: It seems fine - as you say you want to add some "softener".

Comment: IMHO is probably not formal enough if corresponding with a higher authority.  It has a sense of casualness that is the norm in social media.  Even omitting the "humble", "in my opinion" is not necessary because if it's your idea or argument, unless another source is cited, it's be default, your opinion.  IMO or IMHO is often used as a softener or preface but if you want to be taken seriously, just state your reasons without the clutter of a preface...IMO.  :-)

Comment: It is trivially easy to dismiss an opinion, especially if you flat out admit it's just that. So, if you are defending an argument against criticism, you should be working with facts, not opinions. Nobody cares about your opinion anyway, especially if you're the author of the proposal. *Of course* you think it's interesting, otherwise you wouldn't have made it in the first place. Your opinion is clear, you are not supposed to be voicing it again, you are supposed to be *supporting* it. And that can't be done with more opinion, only with more facts. Write down hard facts. Remove everything else.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *in my humble opinion* and its acronym *IMHO* have become trite and virtually meaningless. In context, they often seem disingenuous. The speaker often seems to be *very* sure of the rightness of his or her point of view. I urge losing the phrases completely.

There are standard alternatives that are not so canned sounding:

> - I think my proposal may prove interesting ...
> - My proposal may be of interest ...
> - My proposal may suit your needs ...

The conditional *may* (or similarly *would*) make clear that you are not insisting that your offer is essential or even correct.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "in my humble opinion" is too much of a colloquialism nowadays. Taken literally, it might have acted as a softener once, but idiomatically, as others have pointed out, it comes off as rude and sarcastic.

Personally, I would use something like "I believe", or just "in my opinion" without the word *humble*. Simply stating explicitly that your opinion is your opinion is already a "softener" and can take some of the edge off of what you're saying. Like this:

> **I believe** that my proposal will be interesting because...
>
> **In my opinion,** my proposal is interesting because...

Answer (score 1):

Just say, "My proposal is interesting because . . ." We already know it's your opinion, because you're the one stating it. The rest is filler.

Comment: The way words are used are not always so straightforward. Sometimes the filler can help shape the way the sentence is perceived.

Comment: For example, stating your opinion without calling it your opinion makes it more forceful, while in this case the question asker is looking to deliberately weaken it.